# Simple access query with group by and order by

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a query like this on MS Access:

```
select id_number from students_log group by id_number order by log_date
```

but it gives me this error:

```
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "log_date"
 as part of aggregate function.
```

I am wondering why am I unable to run this simple query and what workaround should i do?

Comment: Access is a little bit tricky. You will have to take the log_date into the select and then group by log_date, too. This would be easier I think: `select distinct id_number,logdate from students_log order by log_date` (untested, but should work).

Comment: @muffi I tried your suggestion but it returns too many `id_number` because it also selected distinct `log_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the latest log_date:

```
select id_number 
from students_log 
group by id_number 
order by max(log_date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked for me but I have to use `min` instead of `max` to sort as `desc`. thanks!